# .Net Maui HttpClient.PostAsync() returns nothing in DEBUG

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

1 solution in VS (2022 v. 17.9.0 preview 2) with 2 projects

- Api with Controllers, using .Net8
- Maui (Win, iOS, Android), using .Net8

The API works just fine, I have no reason to think otherwise. I've tried it with Postman, and through Maui (read below)

I've extracted all relevant code and put it in one ButtonClick to really just test this.

When running the projects in VS (multiple startup) in RELEASE, everything works and the Maui-client gets back a successful response.
However when running in DEBUG my Android-Maui device (Pixel 5 and 6 emulator) just ... nothing happens, when it runs the `httpClient.PostAsync()`.
It does not end up in the Catch nor display some kind of exception (not in the output-window either). After some time it do however throw an exception here, it is not my Cancellation class. I've also tried my machines IP instead of 10.0.2.2
[image]
When running as a Windows-app in DEBUG it do works! So, it feels like it has something todo with the Android part. Is it different manifest-files for different run-configurations? But it feels like the Android-permissions actually do work in DEBUG.

I also want/need to use https (even on loalhost) so there is actually no point to try to go down that road..

The code:

```
    if (Connectivity.Current.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Err", "No internet access.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    if (txtUsername.Text.Trim() == "" || txtPassword.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Missing", "You need to enter username and password", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var requstData = new LoginRequestDto
    {
        Username = txtUsername.Text,
        Password = txtPassword.Text,
        DevicInfo = new DevicInfo { DeviceType = GetDeviceType() }
    };

    string requestJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requstData);
    var contentToSend = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

    try
    {
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
        };
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://10.0.2.2:7218/api/login", contentToSend);
        await DisplayAlert("Request success", response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString(), "OK");
        string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseData = JsonUtils.Deserialize<LoginResponseDto>(responseJson);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
```

Here are the packages my Maui-client use:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)">
      <TreatAsUsed>true</TreatAsUsed>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And this is the Android-manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
    <uses-sdk />
</manifest>
```

Comment: when trying to post to a public service eg: https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create it works, I get back an answer. So.. I guess it is something with this localhost-setup with self-trusted certs... :-(

Comment: Sounds like an async deadlock somewhere. Are you using `.Result` or `.Wait` *anywhere* up the call stack? Side note: `client` `cientHandler` and `response` need `using` to dispose them.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface! I thought so too in the beginning, everything seems to be ok though regarding async, especilly in the ex above where everything is in the same method (buttonClick). And when it works by changing to a public endpoint (or running as release I droped that thought.. but I mightt missed something..) yes, I use using in the code, did remove it here to try to fix that cancellation issue but of course no luck 